# XML response format of SOAP web service

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, soap, wsdl

Hi i am trying to create a SOAP web service on Google app engine i am following this [article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/soap)

this tutorial is showing a simple hello world tutorial i run this program successfully and getting the response

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns3:sayHelloResponse xmlns:ns3="http://example.com/">
<return>Hello, hello!</return>
</ns3:sayHelloResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

which is SOAP1.1 format i have to get the response in SOAP 1.2 format like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:e="http://[app-id].appspot.com/gevents-service">
<env:Body>
</env:Body>
```

for this i added a line on top of Greeter class:

```
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

, then run wsgen command on Greeter class:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\workspace\HelloSoapServer1>wsgen -extension -wsdl:Xsoap1.2 -cp "
./war/WEB-INF/classes" -wsdl -keep -r "./war" -d "./war/WEB-INF/classes" -s "./s
rc" com.example.Greeter
```

where HelloSoapServer1 is project name it successfully created wsdl file of SOAP1.2 format then i again deployed it to appengine i was expecting response output in SOAP1.2 version but  still the response is same as previous.here is some code

Greeter Class

```
package com.example;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;

@WebService
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class Greeter {
  @WebMethod
  public String sayHello(String name){
    return "Hello, " + name+ "!";
  }
  @WebMethod
  public String sayGoodbye(String name){
    return "Goodbye, " + name + "!";
  }
}
```

generated GreeterService.wsdl code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://example.com/" name="GreeterService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com/" schemaLocation="GreeterService_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="sayHello">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHello"/>
  </message>
  <message name="sayHelloResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="sayGoodbye">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayGoodbye"/>
  </message>
  <message name="sayGoodbyeResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayGoodbyeResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="Greeter">
    <operation name="sayHello">
      <input message="tns:sayHello"/>
      <output message="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="sayGoodbye">
      <input message="tns:sayGoodbye"/>
      <output message="tns:sayGoodbyeResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="GreeterPortBinding" type="tns:Greeter">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="sayHello">
      <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="sayGoodbye">
      <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="GreeterService">
    <port name="GreeterPort" binding="tns:GreeterPortBinding">
      <soap12:address location="http://onemoredemo.appspot.com/hellosoapserver1"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

and GreeterService_schema1.xsd code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://example.com/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="sayGoodbye" type="tns:sayGoodbye"/>

  <xs:element name="sayGoodbyeResponse" type="tns:sayGoodbyeResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="sayHello" type="tns:sayHello"/>

  <xs:element name="sayHelloResponse" type="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="sayHello">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="sayHelloResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="sayGoodbye">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="sayGoodbyeResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

as far as i read some articles about SOAP1.2 web services wsgen tool is generating correct wsdl file but when i deploying it it is giving response in format of SOAP1.1 can any one please please help why i am not getting output in the format SOAP1.2 protocol as shown below

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:e="http://[app-id].appspot.com/gevents-service">
    <env:Body>
    </env:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your command begins:

`wsgen -extension -wsdl:Xsoap1.2`, but later has `-wsdl -keep -r` etc... Is it possible that the second appearance of `-wsdl` is overwriting the first to use the default value of 1.1?